# SessionId keeps changing in every curl request in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, rest, session, curl, spring-security

I have the following RestController that returns a SessionId:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/api/sessionid")
public @ResponseBody String getSessionId() {
    return RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId();
}
```

When I use **Postman** or **Chrome browser**, it returns the same **SessionId** on every request. But when I use **CURL** to get the SessionId, it returns a **different** SessionId on every request.

***Why does SessionId change when I use CURL?***

Comment: because you aren't sending the session cookie, which is send by default if you use a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Chrome to send requests to the server: the server uses cookie as session tracking mechanism to identify your session.
When you use CURL: there is no session tracking mechanism, that's why the server creates a new session for every request.

You can read more about session tracking here: https://javapapers.com/servlet/explain-the-methods-used-for-session-tracking/